# How to pass data between renderings in sitecore 9.0.1?

Tags: presentation, renderfield

For passing data between renderings I have seen this [blog](https://chrisperks.co/2017/03/06/a-workaround-for-missing-viewdata-in-sitecore-mvc/). Here they use below method to set data:

```
ContextService.Get().GetCurrent().ViewData.Add("_SharedModel", viewModel);
```

In Sitecore 9.0.1 I couldn't find this kind (**GetCurrent().ViewData**) of method to set viewdata.

How to pass data in Sitecore 9.0.1 or where can I find this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**a) Adding proper references**

You can find "ContextService" in Sitecore.Mvc namespace / assembly.

Just add below using to your razor view:

```
 using Sitecore.Mvc.Common;
```

and in your project references add reference to "Sitecore.Mvc" assembly.

You have couple of options to achieve this. Two of them are below:

1. Using nuget feed

   Sitecore.Mvc.NoReferences

from Sitecore Official nuget feed in version 9.0.171219 (that is correct one for Sitecore 9 Update 1). More information about nuget feeds can be found here -> https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecore_public_nuget_packages_faq

[image]

2. Copying Sitecore.Mvc.dll from bin folder to your shared lib folder in your project and reference it in csproj project file

**b) Fixing GetCurrent method call**

You should fix your code like this:

```
ContextService.Get().GetCurrent<ViewContext>().ViewData.Add("_SharedModel", viewModel);
```

Comment: But it dont have GetCurrent().ViewData property.

Comment: I have updated my answer to fix this problem